# Thymeleaf: <label> to have dynamic text concatenated with static text Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, append, thymeleaf, dynamic-text

I'm trying to append some text to a dynamic text as shown below:

```
<label th:text="Hello ${worldText}"></label>
```

But the UI throws:

`TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "Hello ${worldText}`

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

An easy solution would be to insert a span to the label:

```
<label>Hello <span th:text="${worldText}"></span></label>
```

But i would prefer to combine text and variables like this:

```
<label th:text="'Hello' + ${worldText}"></label>
```

Comment: Worked for me. Former seems like a work around, but latter suites well in my case, I have some more things to append in the text. Thanks :)

Comment: Seems `text` is not an official attribute for `<label>`, therefore your first approach is better

Answer (score 3):

Another straightforward solution is

```
<label th:text="${'Hello ' + worldText}"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some other ways,

```
// 1. Using the <th:block> element
<label>Hello <th:block th:text="${worldText}"></th:block></label>

// 2. Using string concatenation
<label th:text="${'Hello ' + worldText}"></label>

// 3. Using the pipe (|) character
<label th:text="|Hello ${worldText}|"></label>

// 4. Using expression inlining
<label>Hello [[${worldText}]]</label>

// 5. You could prepare a variable in your controller
// In contoller,
model.addAttribute("helloWorld", "Hello " + worldText);
// In template,
<label th:text="${helloWorld}"></label>
```

The result will always be,

```
<label>Hello variable-value</label>
```